# External Content Library Pagination

Tags: 2013, ecl

Trying to get back lots of items using the ECL.

Seems that it tops out at about 500 items or so and we cannot set up pagination to get back more content etc.

Has anyone else met this?

Anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks

Graeme

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "we cannot set up pagination" mean exactly? 1) You cannot set it up in ECL, 2) Your external system can't paginate the data it returns, 3) something else?

Comment: The issue is that we go get the content from the external system say the first 10 records, and then Tridion does not know when we ask for the next page to get the next page from the external system due to Tridion being stateless....

Comment: As Rob already mentioned pagination is supported in ECL. The state is maintained in the Tridion UI. The UI sends the pageIndex parameter when calling GetFolderContent or Search. The provider is responsible for determining page size. IFolderContent returned from GetFolderContent and Search allows the provider to send information back to the UI driving the pagination control in the list. If you call the API through something else than the UI (templating, eventhandler, ...) then it is your responsibility to maintain state for pagination.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't actually used this in the ECL I've written and you may have already spotted these but there is a `pageIndex` parameter on the `GetFolderContent` method from the `IContentLibraryContext` interface

```
public IFolderContent GetFolderContent(IEclUri parentFolderUri, int pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes)
```

I'm not sure how the CME passes that through through or where the pagination controls appear.

The `Search` method on the same interface also seems to support paging:

```
public IFolderContent Search(IEclUri contextUri, string searchTerm, int pageIndex, int numberOfItems)
```

Sorry I can't give a more complete answer but this might be a start.

Comment: The pagination control will appear above the list, next to the Toggle View and Search fields (well, the search field might be hidden if the provider does not support search).